# Run Angular directive code after DOM has updated

Tags: angular

I have a directive I use to focus the first field that has the ng-invalid class in a form. This has been working well for me but we have added the ability to collapse some parts of the form in an accordion like manner. Problem is that now parts of the form that are not visible stop the form submitting but the user is left scratching their head as to where the error is. I have tried setting the property that expands the collapsed section then call the focus but the focus is called before the DOM updates and the section has expanded.

What is the Angular way of calling a piece of code after the DOM has updated?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusFirstInvalid]'
})
export class FocusFirstInvalidDirective {
  @Output()
  submitOnValid: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
  onSubmit(event) {
    const elm = event.target;
    elm.classList.add('submitted');
    let invalid = elm.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid');

    if (invalid.length) {
      invalid[0].focus();
    } else {
      this.submitOnValid.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you collapse the form?

Comment: <section [hidden]="sectionHidden" (click)="sectionHidden = !sectionHidden"></section>

Comment: How about settting sectionHidden=true before focus() and  keeping a track of which section by addind a property in the directive?